# The end-to-end Training Process for Knowledge Distillation

Tags: deep-learning, knowledge-distillation

I'm a bit confused on the complete training process for Knowledge Distillation. I was reading the Geoffrey Hinton "Distilling the Knowledge in a Neural Network" 2015 [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02531.pdf) and some random blog plots to figure out how to actually train it. However, I don't see any end-to-end training example for that paper. So, here is what I understand and want to confirm the training process. Let's say we will train one big binary classification teacher network and distill the knowledge to student network.

1. Train the Large Teacher Network
2. Distill the Knowledge

   - Use the temperature to soften the softmax (where T is temperature and it's used to reduce confidence such as [2.0, 0.5] with T=1 is [0.82, 0.18] and T=2 is [0.68, 0.32].)
     $$\text{softmax}(x_i) = \frac{e^{\frac{x_i}{T}}}{\sum_{j=1}^{N} e^{\frac{x_j}{T}}}$$
   - Then, prepare the subset of training dataset with new labels which are soft targets instead of hard targets [0, 1, 1, ...].

     - Soft targets = [[0.68, 0.32], [0.44, 0.56], [0.39, 0.61], ...]
   - That new subset of dataset with soft targets is called transfer set.
3. Loss Function

   - To make it simple, let's say I'll use the CrossEntropyLoss with class probabilities between my outputs (with same temperate as transfer set) and soft targets.
4. That's it. Then, I can start the distillation training with transfer set.

Is this process/flow correct?

Comment: Hi @Chuu, welcome to the site. If you find the answers to your question useful, please consider upvoting them. Also, please consider accepting one (with the tick mark ✓ next to it) if you consider it correct or, alternatively, please describe in a comment why you consider it incorrect or not clear enough.

Comment: Hi @noe, thanks for answering the question. I'm sorry for late to upvote, as I was busy with other stuffs. Thanks for clarifying my doubt and providing an example for text generation. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct.

Nevertheless, you may see some variations, e.g. when the number of classes is very large, the size of the transfer dataset can be huge (this is the case of text generation, where the vocabulary size can be around 50k); to mitigate that, instead of storing the probabilities, you may store the vector before obtaining the logits (together with the final linear layer params) and then compute the probabilities from it on the fly during the distillation training.